# json.dumps doesn't works with dictionary of unicode strings

Tags: python, json, flask

I have list:

```
 [{'probabilities': {'wrong': 0.99991131, 'correct': 8.873138e-05}, 'sentence': u'hello world'}, {'probabilities': {'wrong': 0.99996436, 'correct': 3.5610035e-05}, 'sentence': u'London is the capital of Great Britain'}]
```

json.dumps doesn't transform this list to string and it even doesn't throw any exception

there is full code:

```
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

from network import predict
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def main():
    res = []

    for obj in request.json:
        res.append({'sentence': obj['sentence'], 'probabilities': predict(obj['sentence'])})

    print('res', res)

    try:
        print('json.dumps(res)', json.dumps(res, ensure_ascii=False))
    except Exception:
        print('Exception', Exception)

    return json.dumps(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Then what *does* happen? Is all the flask stuff actually required for a [mcve]?

Comment: I guess it‘s not about the `json.dumps`, it's your predict function. I've run it without the predict function. it worked with or without unicode string. can you confirmed the predict function worked properly.

Comment: I've solved this. problem was with predict function. it was returning some number type, which json.dumps doesn't support.